Maven: Split target-output to dependency and custom jar?
I am using a Java project with Maven.
Normally I like to get 1 big jar-file that includes all.
But now I got problems with my internet-bandwith - the transfer of the jar (that is approx. 100MB) is really problematic. Thats life at the countryside...
How can I get out of the build process a jar with all dependency-libs that I not need to transfer by every update and then a jar that includes my custom code that is small and I can update easily and fast??
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>MyPrj1</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AppA</name>
    <description>My App No A</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
              <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
              <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Sice you are using spring-boot have a look at the layered jar. You probably only need to transfer the layer with your application jars.

I found out how to extract all 4 layers out of the single jar. But I do not want to use it in a docker image. How can I start my app when having this 4 directories (application, dependencies, snapshot-dependencies and spring-boot-loader)?

You could either recreate the layered jar at the other end or give https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/specification/executable-jar/property-launcher.html a try with the loader.path argument pointing to those 4 directories.
